# Laravel - Json Encode Works Fine But Returns Malformed UTF-8 Error Regardless

Tags: json, laravel, symfony, exception, php-7.4

**Problem**

The JSON is returned correctly encoded but `json_last_error` equates to `5` thus Laravel throws this exception on response creation in `JsonResponse->setData()`.

**Related References**

A resolved bug report for symfony and PHP 7.3: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31447 mentions this exact issue. That is:

`If a json_encode()/json_decode() without JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR encoding option set throws an error, any subsequent call to the same with that flag set will not reset the error of the previous call.`

The `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` RFC mentions this behavior as by design: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/json_throw_on_error

Unfortunately Laravel's code uses the flag but does not cater for this behavior and throws exception if `json_last_error()` returns a non zero value. Which in this case should have been ignored as it will always reference the previous error. Perhaps a version check should be added.

**Investigation**

I have also searched the bowls of my application and haven't found the misbehaving `json_encode/json_decode` without `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` set so I am sure it is internal to Laravel before Middleware calls.

**Additional Context**

This suddenly started happening today in our server. It happens when users connect to the server through the web app from select systems. Even though system kind should not affect server side response generation but still web app always generates this error for specific PCs/Mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed Hack**

After sifting through the Symfony bug report, the easiest workaround I have found is to just clear the error through an inconsequential `json_encode('1')` call. Which effectively resets the error code to `0` and the later JSON methods work fine.

Fortunately we have our own response generation class so just adding this before the hand-off to Laravel works fine.

Still this is a hack. I am more interested in a better solution or any bug fix available.